# Hot to fetch UserId from aspnet_Users table while using Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

I am using windows authentication in my application

```
if(User.IsInRole("Supervisor"))
{
//do something
}
```

which is working as expected.

Now i want to fetch a UserId of the logged in user from aspnet_Users table . I tried using Membership.GetUser , which did not worked.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

No direct way but you can use `ProviderUserKey` property of `MembershipUser` class like below:

```
        var user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
        if (user != null)
        {
            var userId = user.ProviderUserKey;
        }
```